# Пустая страница после отправки формы в базу данных?

Tags: form, wamp

После отправки формы в базу данных попадаю на страницу register.php(файл, в котором написан скрипт подключения к бд и отправки данных формы). Так как она не оформлена, на ней ничего не отображается. Я хочу чтобы пользователя перенапрявляло на стартовую страницу index.php после отправки формы.
Код скрипта register.php:

```
//подключение к базе данных
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$hostpassword = "";
$dbname = "accounts";

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $hostpassword, $dbname);
//sql запрос на добавление информации из формы
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_accounts(login, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $login, $password);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

//$url = 'http://localhost/website';
header("Location: ". $url ."");
//exit();
```

При использовании последних двух строк меня не пускает на страницу регистрации(я так понял, меня сразу после перехода на страницу регистрации перенаправляет на основную страницу)

Код страницы регистрации:

```
    <?php 
        require_once "header.html";
        require_once "php/register.php"
    ?>
    <div class="register">
    <p class="reg">REGISTER</p>
        <div class="register-form">
            <form action="php\register.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="login" />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в неверном пути к целевому файлу. Указал абсолютный путь, поменял подключение на mysqli, работает как задумывалось